# Caliburn.Micro navigation with parameters

Tags: windows-phone-8, navigation, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to navigate between 2 pages in my application : ReplayView and ReplayDetailView.
The navigation works fine but I can't access the parameters in ReplayDetailViewModel.

Here is the code from ReplayViewModel :

```
        public void ShowDetail()
    {
        navigationService.UriFor<ReplayDetailViewModel>()
            .WithParam(x => x.progName, selectedProgram.titre)
            .WithParam(x => x.progPrez, selectedProgram.animateur.prenom + ' ' + selectedProgram.animateur.nom)
            .WithParam(x => x.progTime, selectedProgram.description)
            .WithParam(x => x.progId, selectedProgram.id)
            .Navigate();
    }
```

I checked with BuildUri() and the query string is built correctly.

All the properties are defined in ReplayDetailViewModel :

```
        private string name;
    private string time;
    private string prez;
    private int id;

    public string progName
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => progName);
        }
    }
    public string progPrez
    {
        get { return prez; }
        set
        {
            prez = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => progPrez);
        }
    }
    public string progTime
    {
        get { return time; }
        set
        {
            time = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => progTime);
        }
    }
    public int progId
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            id = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => progId);
        }
    }
```

Both the ViewModels extends Screen and ReplayView is inside a pivot.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "I can't access the parameters in ReplayDetailViewModel"?

Comment: which version of the framework too? 1.5.2 or 2.0